# The Billiards Problem

Tags: calculation-puzzle

We have a billiards table with height $h$ and width $w$, as illustrated in the image below. Notice that it has no pockets.
[image: Billiards Table]

A ball with radius $r\ll w$ (can be regarded as a point) is propelled from the bottom-left corner at an angle $5°\leq\alpha\leq 85°$ with respect the horizontal axis (as depicted in the figure). The movement is constrained to a plane, so there is no depth involved. The velocity of the ball is irrelevant.

There are no dissipative effects, so the ball will keep bouncing forever with no loss of energy. In other words, the collisions (ball-walls) are *perfectly elastic* (the angles are conserved before and after a collision).

1. Find the angle $\alpha$ that *maximizes* the *number of bounces* until the ball returns to the *first collision point*. How many bounces $n(h,w,\alpha)$ will it take for this to happen? *If you think there is no angle $\alpha$ for which the ball returns to the first collision point, demonstrate it.*

**NOTE:** The *first collision point* is the point $(x_0,y_0)$ at which the ball first touches a wall.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvote.

Comment: May the downvoters at least leave a comment about why they don't like this puzzle? Thanks.

Comment: How tall are the edges of the table, how high off the table was the ball released, and how fast was the ball thrown?

Comment: Does the speed matter in this 2D problem? It all happens in the XY plane, so you can say the edges have depth. Is that why you downvoted?

Comment: Anyway, I modified the puzzle to make it clear. Is it OK now? (I wanted to say you *cannot* say the edges have depth above)

Comment: We might as well start at the first time the ball hits the wall.  If we launch at an irrational slope, we will never return to the first collision point.  This invalidates the whole question. -1  There are certainly some angles for which the ball returns to the first collision point, but they are of measure zero in the arc around the launch point.

Comment: So you downvote the question because it is too trivial for you? This is starting to get a bit pedantic. Know, by the way, this is an old question in an old book by a reknown author. Now that the answer is too trivial, should I shred the book? Or better: let's blame the mathematician for such a question. If this problem had been made by Einstein it would be a reference problem these days. But nah! This was just copied by an average guy from an average book written by a trivial author. I know where this is going.

Comment: And by the way, you didn't even use a formula, that is what's asked in the problem. *Demonstrate* the ball will never return to the first collision point regardless of $\alpha $

Comment: The ball can return to the first collision point if the ball bounces back along the angle it came from when it hits a corner exactly, but its behaviour in that case is not really specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

> as alpha approaches 0, the number of bounces approaches infinity. There is no true solution to this because any alpha you give I can provide a smaller alpha which will have more bounces

  2.

> any angle not equal to tan(h/w) will cause a rectangle of some size to be drawn, but I think I may be misunderstanding what you mean by "draw a rectangle"

Comment: 1.
>! No valid answer. The problem is about maximizing the number of bounces *until* the first collision point is reached. As your reasoning is logical, you didn't prove there is an $\alpha$ for which the number of bounces is greater than a smaller one. You didn't even prove the ball will ever reach its first colision point, $(x_0, y_0)$

Comment: A new restriction has been added. The angle must lie within 5 and 85 degrees.

Comment: my answer still applies as alpha approaches tan(h/w)

Comment: Your answer for the second question is also wrong. Give it a deep thinking!

Comment: For a rectangle to be drawn, the ball needs to bounce between 4 stationary points.

Comment: any alpha between 0 and tan(h/w) exclusive will draw a rectangle before it collides with the bottom wall. any alpha between tan(h/w) and 90 exclusive will draw a rectangle before colliding with the left wall. angles 0, tan(h/w), and 90 will rebound directly to the starting point

Comment: The rectangle, as I said, must be stationary, which means 4 vertices with constant coordinates. The ball will bounce between these 4 vertices and no other(s). This will only happen for very specific angles. Hope you understood now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/OVvAGky they all draw rectangles. do you mean rectangle with all its vertices touching the walls?

Comment: Yes, they should be on the wall. My fault. And remember: the vertices must be all 4 the same.

Comment: Given the first collision point $(x_0, y_0)$, the rectangule must have coordinates $A=(x_0, y_0)$, $B=(x_1, y_1)$, $C=(x_2, y_2)$, $D=(x_3, y_3)$

Answer (score 2):

For part 2.

> There can be no rectangle. First, we show no rectangle can contain the starting point. Consider this point. This lies in the corner of the table, so in any drawn rectangle must also be a corner. But, this means the ball must return to this point at a 90 degree angle to the direction it left from. Since the whole corner is only 90 degrees, it must either come from off the table, impossible, or the initial angle must be 0. However, an initial angle of 0 would bounce straight back and not form a rectangle.
> Now, we show that any rectangle is a closed loop. Consider any corner of the rectangle. This must be on a wall, and must be a 90 degree angle. Thus, both entry and exit angles must be 45 degrees. Since the walls are 45 degrees from each other, this means that once an angle leaves a wall at 45 degree, all subsequent angles will be 45 degree angles. However, this means that when the point returns to the starting corner, it will be at a 45 degree angle and must then repeat the rectangle. By simply reversing the direction, we see that this means all rectangles are closed loops.
>  If every rectangle is a closed loop, and no rectangle can contain the starting point, then the starting point cannot create a rectangle.

Comment: The rectangle must be made from the first collision point ahead.

Comment: I would say that there is no rectangle with an edge ray that could point to the origin. As each point of the rectangle lies on the edge, any ray would be off the table.

Comment: @JonTheMon: Given the first collision point $(x_0, y_0)$, the rectangule must have coordinates $A=(x_0, y_0)$, $B=(x_1, y_1)$, $C=(x_2, y_2)$, $D=(x_3, y_3)$

Comment: Made it clear in the puzzle, check out.

Comment: Hey, you made your answer visible. Hide it so others don't accidentally look at it!

Comment: Whoops. What's the format for multiple hidden paragraphs?

Comment: SE doesn't like consecutive spoiler paragraphs for some reason. You can insert line breaks instead by putting two spaces at the end of every line.

Comment: Hmm, a hardcoded <BR> seemed to work instead. Thanks!

Comment: The first point is not in the corner of the table, Cain. I think that's what's leading you to error!

Comment: The first point is the point where the ball first touches a wall *after* having been launched.

Comment: @JoseLopez But the ball starts in the bottom-left corner, no?

Comment: Yes. Look at this image to see an example of a possible rectangle: http://pasteboard.co/P6VBOUW.png

Comment: (It is not a rectangle, strictly speaking! So I was wrong calling it a rectangle). Anyway, the answer is NO, and this question is a bit silly so I will delete it from the original puzzle.

Comment: @JoseLopez So my answer was correct, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the question was a nonsense anyway. Good work!